# Ajax JQuery - Append Returned Variables + Input Button and Span to Div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, append, concatenation

Using the variables from an Ajax request to create an input button and span tag, which show the number of likes per post (this is for a message board), but the concatenation of fields using JQuery is beyond me. Had this working using just php/html before, but wanted to make it cleaner using Ajax/JQuery.

Trying to achieve the below logic using JQuery:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="post-action">

<input type="button" value="Like" id="like_<?php echo $ID . "_" . $UserID; ?>" class="like" style="<?php if($type == 1){ echo "color: #ffa449;"; } ?>" />&nbsp;(<span id="likes_<?php echo $ID . "_" . $UserID; ?>"><?php echo $total_likes; ?></span>)&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery basic attempt but really not sure of the syntax/logic (didn't populate html on page, Ajax request is working though):

```
success: function(response) {

$(".content").html("")
for( var key of Object.keys( response ) ) {
$( '.content' ).append( `<div class="post-action">
    <input type="button" value="Like" id="like_${response[key].ID}_${response[key].UserID}></div>`);    
    }
 }
```

JSON array data returned from Ajax request:

```
$data[] = array ( 'ID' => $row['ID'], 'UserID' => $row['UserID'], 'UserIDLikeChk' => $row['UserIDLikeChk'], 'MessageText' => nl2br(htmlentities($row['MessageText'],ENT_COMPAT|ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8") ), 'cntLikes' => $row['cntLikes'], 'Type' => $row['Type'] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** for Data Structure :

```
    success: function(response) {
    $(".content").html("");
      $.each(response, function() {
          $.each($(this), function(i, item) {
var mycss =(item.Type == 1) ? ' style="color: #ffa449;"' :'';
              $( '.content' ).append( '<div class="post-action"><input '+mycss+' type="button" value="Like" id="like_'+item.ID+'_'+item.UserID+'"><span id="likes_'+item.ID+'_'+item.UserID+'">'+item.cntLikes+'</span></div>');
          });
      });
    }
```

Strings and variables were mixed without separation in your code. 
The **+** character in Javascript is the alternative to the Dot **(.)** used for string concatenation in pHp.

And it's better to avoid line breaks while appending content.

I had to encode your array in pHp to get an idea of what you are getting and still I'm not sure but I assume here you could receive multiple objects.

And don't forget to add `dataType: 'json',` to your ajax options.

Comment: Thank you @Bilel. I've amended the original question. It is a JSON array being return from the Ajax request. Would your syntax also work for adding in the CSS. And I wasn't quite sure how I would add in the if logic to the string. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: A translation from php to javascript :) I hope it works for you now...

Comment: Would you be able to explain the logic behind the two each loops in the answer? I'm still a bit of a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: Following this json structure , that I found in the php code we could receive a list of objects inside an array. So the parent each() is for the parent array and the nested each() is for looping through it's nested objects. You don't have to use this nested loop if your parent array have only one list... And you replace it with $.each(response[0],.... Php would decide which optimal json structure we follow. So yes for optimisation purpose, you could change the code I wrote above.